# Function - Unorderable Types list() > int()

Tags: python, list, integer, comparison

```py
values = []

def posNumAvg(values):
    average = 0
    sum = 0
    if n in values > 0:
        sum = sum + n
    return sum/len(values)
```

Gives me the message:

```
Unorderable types: list() > int()
```

How do I fix this so that each value in list `values` can be compared against 0?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, and tag your question with the primary language (I think that's Python here, but edit the tags if I'm wrong).  Assuming it is Python, you look as if you're trying to do some sort of list comprehension in the `if` statement, which should surely be a `for` loop anyway.  Go back and read the manual.

Comment: You cant do this: ' if n in values > 0:' How does the `values` look like and what would be expected output?

Comment: I want to input a command to divide the sum of the negative numbers in the "values" list by the number of negatives in the "values" list, in other words: negative number average

Answer (score 1):

`if n in values > 0:` has a whole bunch of things wrong with it:

- `values > 0` is comparing a list to an int - something you can't do in Python
- `n in values > 0` is comparing an undefined variable to a broken expression (which you also can't do)
- `average` is never used, which isn't a *problem* but may not be what you wanted

Try this:

```py
def posNumAvg(values):
    return sum(n for n in values if n > 0)/len(values)
```

Python has a built-in `sum` function that you can use to get the sum of all items in an iterable (in this case, the generator object), which we then divide by the length of the original list of values.

Comment: values = []

def numList():
    while -9999 not in values:
        x = int(input("Enter any amount of numbers or -9999 to quit: "))
        values.append(x)
    values.remove(-9999)
    return values



def NonPosAvg(values): #Key2
    return sum(n for n in values if n > 0)/len(values)

print ("The list of numbers entered is:",numList())

Display_Avg= {}
Display_Avg['AvgPosAvg:']= NonPosAvg(values)


print(Display_Avg)

Comment: Ok I have it working, but taking your exact code, how can I divide by only the negative numbers in "values" list (instead of total items in list)?

Comment: @rustyh. `len(n for n in values if n < 0)` gives you the number of negative numbers in the list. replace the `len` with `sum` to get the sum of the negatives.

Comment: Just tried it, here's the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Assignment6Part2.py", line 26, in <module>
    Display_Avg['NonPosAvg:']= NonPosAvg(values)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Assignment6Part2.py", line 15, in NonPosAvg
    return sum(n for n in values if n < 0)/len(n for n in values if n < 0)
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Comment: @rustyh. ah, sorry should be len([n for n in values if n < 0])